# react is posting data to console, but data is not successfully making it mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

i'm having an issue where my form data is posting to the chrome console, but the payload is not making it's way to the sql database when the query is fired. is it how i've set up axios in the form that is preventing the payload from firing? or is it in my app.post request in the backend?

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njcth.png)

**react form using axios**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

export default class AddVisitorForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       lastName: '',
       firstName: ''
    }
  }


  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ 
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
     })
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state)

    const body = this.setState
    axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/addactor',
    data: body
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
  }


  render() {
    const { lastName, firstName } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input defaultValue='last name' type="text" name="lastName" onChange={this.onChange } value={lastName} />
            <input defaultValue='first name' type="text" name="firstName" onChange={this.onChange } value={firstName} />
          <button type="submit">Add Guest</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

**express backend**

```
const Actor = require('./models/Actor');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  //we say what we want to allow, you can whitelist IPs here or domains
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
  //what kind of headers we are allowing
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");  

  //check for the options request from browsers
  //this will always be sent
  if(req.method === "OPTIONS"){
      //tell the browser what he can ask for
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
      //we just respond with OK status code
      return res.status(200).json({
          "statusMessage": "ok"
      });
  }

  next();
});



app.post('/addactor', function (req, res) {
  Actor.create({
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    firstName: req.body.firstName
  })
  .then(function (Actor) {
    res.json(Actor);
  });
});



app.listen(8000);
```

**actor model**

```
const sequelize = require('../database/sequelize');
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports = sequelize.define('actor', {
  id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    field: 'actor_id',
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    field: 'last_name',
    defaultValue: '',
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true
  },
  firstName: {
    field: 'first_name',
    defaultValue: '',
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true
  },
  }, {
  timestamps: false
});
```

from here, i get a this message in my terminal, and my table rows are left empty besides the auto-incremented ID.

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `actor` (`actor_id`,`last_name`,`first_name`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?);
```

[empty rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPCzh.png)

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.body)` inside `app.post('/addactor'` ?

Comment: just tried this. here's the response in terminal.[Object: null prototype] {
  'function (partialState, callback) {\n  if (!(typeof partialState ': "== 'object' || typeof partialState === 'function' || partialState == null)) {\n" +
    '    {\n' +
    '      throw Error("setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.");\n' +
    '    }\n' +
    '  }\n' +
    '\n' +
    "  this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback, 'setState');\n" +
    '}'

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `handleSubmit()`. Specifically in the setup of the `data`/body for the axios POST request. You are setting the value of  `body` to that of the function `this.setState`, instead of just the component's `this.state`:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state);
  const body = this.state;
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/addactor",
    data: body
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Basically change `const body = this.setState` to `const body = this.state`.

Comment: Alexander, that was exactly it. wow. thank you so much. I looked at this code over and over yesterday banging my head.

Comment: and i don't have enough reputation to upvote, so if this thread helps anyone else, please give the man my upvote.

Comment: Good to hear. While you can't upvote, you can mark the answer as "correct" by clicking the check mark. Thanks!